# cordovawebviewclient cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on cordova application(Phonegap). I am using the following method in my Android main.java

```
protected CordovaWebViewClient makeWebViewClient(CordovaWebView webView) {
    appView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {}
    });}
```

In previous projects it is working fine, but in the new project it is saying "can not resolve symbol CordovaWebViewClient". Don't know why. I am having trouble with it. Is it because of the cordova update?
Help to resolve this....

Comment: try with org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewClient instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordova 4 removed the `CordovaWebViewClient` class ([see this commit](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/efcedabee098d28e7c3e87dc3a7414b4a235a5fc)). They've made many breaking changes to support external webviews, like Crosswalk.

See the [4.0 release notes](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/15/cordova-android-4.0.0.html) for more information.

Comment: I have imported org.apache.cordova.*, it is ok with it. If I import the  org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient then it is showing an error

Comment: What version of cordova are you using?

Comment: And what version of cordova have you used in past projects?

Comment: right now using latest one & previous ones I am using 3.0

Comment: I reverted my new project to the 3.0, then it is working fine