# Why CordovaWebViewClient not working in Cordova 6 anymore

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I have written custom webviewclient class to override `onPageStarted, onPageFinished etc` in cordova 3.7 which was working fine.

In following code is I have hosted the www directory to web server and interacting cordova plugins from there (barcodescanner, nfc, bluetooth etc).

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();

        loadUrl("https://example.com");
    }

    public class CustomCordovaWebViewClient extends CordovaWebViewClient {

        public CustomCordovaWebViewClient(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView view) {
            super(cordova, view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            Log.i("CSP Log", "onPageStarted: " + url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.i("CSP Log", "onPageFinished: " + url);
        }

        @Override
        public void doUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, String url, boolean isReload){
            super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }

    }

}
```

After a year, I have migrated project from cordova 3.7 to cordova 6 but I found above code broken like `CordovaWebViewClient, super.onPageStarted etc` can't resolve symbols. I also tried `CordovaWebViewImpl` and confused myself.

After searching alot on google I found solution which were mostly given in 2011-14 which are not applicable. I couldn't found cordova docs helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was replaced by `SystemWebViewClient`

You should do something like this:

```
SystemWebView wv = (SystemWebView)appView.getView();
wv.setWebViewClient(new SystemWebViewClient((SystemWebViewEngine)appView.getEngine()){
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        Log.i("CSP Log", "onPageStarted: " + url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.i("CSP Log", "onPageFinished: " + url);
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, String url, boolean isReload){
        super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know why it openning url redirect calls in browser instead of application

Comment: do you have an allow-intent tag for http/https in your config.xml? remove it

Comment: Sorry I was away in night. After removing allow intent redirect doesn't work

Comment: Then instead of removing allow-intent, replace them with allow-navigation

Answer (score 1):

**Cordova 4** removed the `CordovaWebViewClient` : [look here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/efcedabee098d28e7c3e87dc3a7414b4a235a5fc)

You may use `WebViewClient` instead of `CordovaWebViewClient` (The [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin use that for override `onPageStarted` event).

```
public class CustomCordovaWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache cordova removed CordovaWebViewClient inorder to support external webviews like Crosswalk. If you check out the `14 changed files` link in the following [commit link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/efcedabee098d28e7c3e87dc3a7414b4a235a5fc), you could see CordovaWebViewClient is removed and AndroidWebViewClient is added.

So i guess you cannot use the same old code work in Cordova 6.0

You can probably try using `org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewClient` instead.

Infact, the same question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571578/cordovawebviewclient-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type) and it was also accepted. So i believe this is the possible solution to the issue. Hope it helps.