# Ionic Cordova InAppBrowser

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have an hybrid app built with:
Ionic 5.4.16
Cordova 10.0.0
AngularCLI 9.0.2
Android sdk 29

I open an URL using Cordova In App Browser https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser .
This URL is a chat page, and in this URL i need access to front and back cameras and microphone, but when I open it, the page doesn't have the access.
It seems it doesn't use the permissions declared in my config.xml, while the app it uses these permissions in its lifecycle.
In my "Android platform" section i declared:

```
        <config-file mode="merge" parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
        </config-file>
```

```
private iab: InAppBrowser
....
const ref = this.iab.create(url, '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=no');
```

Is there any other permission I need to declare?
Do you have any suggest?

Comment: this appears to be a known issue. The ionic plugin is simply the cordova plugin with a little extra sugar.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/706

Comment: Also see this thread for further discussion and potential workarounds and pit falls. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557767/does-getusermedia-works-in-ionic-webview-in-android-app